# Using iterated variables with regex

Tags: regex, perl, loops, nested-loops

The point of the overall script is to:

step 1) open a single column file and read off first entry.

step 2) open a second file containing lots of rows and columns, read off EACH line one at a time, and find anything in that line that matches the first entry from the first file.

step3) if a match is found, then "do something constructive", and if not, go to the first file and take the second entry and repeat step 2 and step 3, and so on...

here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; #use warnings;

unless(@ARGV) {
    print "\usage: $0 filename\n\n"; # $0 name of the program being executed
    exit;
}

my $list = $ARGV[0]; 
chomp( $list );
unless (open(LIST, "<$list")) {
print "\n I can't open your list of genes!!! \n";
exit;
}

my( @list ) = (<LIST>);
close LIST;


open (CHR1, "<acembly_chr_sorted_by_exon_count.txt") or die;

my(@spreadsheet) = (<CHR1>);
close CHR1;


for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @list; $i++ ) {

   print "$i in list is $list[$i]\n";   

   for (my $j = 1; $j < scalar @spreadsheet; $j++ ) {

        #print "$spreadsheet[$j]\n";
        if ( $spreadsheet[$j] ) {
            print "will $list[$i] match with $spreadsheet[$j]?\n";
            }
        else { print "no match\n" };    

   } #for
} #for
```

I plan to use a regex in the line `if ( $spreadsheet[$j] ) {` but am having a problem at this step as it is now.  On the first interation, the line `print "will $list[$i] match with $spreadsheet[$j]?\n";` prints `$list[$i]` OK but does not print `$spreadsheet[$j]`. This line will print both variables correctly on the second and following iterations.  I do not see why?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the `my $j = 1;` starting index?

Comment: no, i tried that, it doesn't affect anything. should have mentioned that.

Comment: How many entires in the first file?  Can multiple first-file entries match the same line in the second file?  Do you treat each match the same way or differently, depending upon what was matched?

Comment: What happens if you `print $spreadsheet[1]` before you begin your loop? Does it print anything?

Comment: I think @codnodder was correct about the lurking whitespace issue he mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance nothing looks overtly incorrect. As mentioned in the comments the `$j = 1` looks questionable but perhaps you are skipping the first row on purpose.

Here is a more perlish starting point that is tested. If it does not work then you have something going on with your input files.

Note the extended trailing whitespace removal. Sometimes if you open a WINDOWS file on a UNIX machine and use `chomp`, you can have embedded `\r` in your text that causes weird things to happen to printed output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; #use warnings;

unless(@ARGV) {
    print "\usage: $0 filename\n\n"; # $0 name of the program being executed
    exit;
}

my $list = shift;
unless (open(LIST, "<$list")) {
    print "\n I can't open your list of genes!!! \n";
    exit;
}

open(CHR1, "<acembly_chr_sorted_by_exon_count.txt") or die;
my @spreadsheet = map { s/\s+$//; $_ } <CHR1>;
close CHR1;

# s/\s+$//; is like chomp but trims all trailing whitespace even
# WINDOWS files opened on a UNIX system.

for my $item (<LIST>) {
    $item =~ s/\s+$//; # trim all trailing whitespace
    print "==> processing '$item'\n";   
    for my $row (@spreadsheet) {
        if ($row =~ /\Q$item\E/) { # see perlre for \Q \E
            print "match    '$row'\n";
        }
        else {
            print "no match '$row'\n";
        }    
   }
}

close LIST;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right about the weird white spaces. I am trying your version, which looks very Perl-y.  I am told my Perl looks too much like C, but I am progressing. Anyway, what is the significance of `my $list = shift`?

Comment: Oh, I see. Here, `shift` is pulling off the element stored in @ARGV. Correct?